# Enabling RDP using autounattend.xml answer file

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, unattended

I'm trying to enable RDP automatically within my `autounattended.xml` file. I found different sources like [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/security-compliance-and-identity/enabling-remote-desktop-using-unattended-setup/ba-p/246499), which seems to be the most clean one, since they'll not disable the entire firewall. Instead, they add an rule to allow RDP traffic. Other sources like [this](https://github.com/jbrek/windows11-autounattend.xml/blob/main/autounattend.xml) doesn't even are about this, they only set `fDenyTSConnections`. However, [this article](https://gist.github.com/kylep/51bb4a6233de279cd690c6b6ea329b19) disables the firewall, but sets some registry keys to enable RDP.

It seems that the firewall rules works, but RDP itself got not enabled, which can be seen in the system propertys. The `FirstLogonCommands` were executed, which is proofed by the fact that the explorer file extensions are shown and the corresponding log file exists.

According to [the MS documentation for `fDenyTSConnections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-terminalservices-localsessionmanager-fdenytsconnections), this is the right attribute for enabling RDP and only the firewallrules are required additionally. So what am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <fDenyTSConnections>false</fDenyTSConnections>
        </component>
        <component name="Networking-MPSSVC-Svc" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <FirewallGroups>
                <FirewallGroup wcm:action="add" wcm:keyValue="rd1">
                    <Active>true</Active>
                    <Group>Remote Desktop</Group>
                    <Profile>all</Profile>
                </FirewallGroup>
            </FirewallGroups>
        </component>
         <component name="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDP-WinStationExtensions" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS">
            <UserAuthentication>0</UserAuthentication>
        </component> 
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <CommandLine>cmd /k reg add &quot;HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced&quot; /v HideFileExt /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f &gt;&gt; C:\ul_xml_customizations_log.txt &amp;&amp; exit</CommandLine>
                    <Description>Dateinamenserweiterung im Explorer anzeigen</Description>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <CommandLine>cmd /c &quot;REG ADD &quot;HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server&quot; /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f&quot;</CommandLine>
                    <Order>2</Order>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <CommandLine>cmd /c &quot;REG ADD &quot;HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp&quot; /v UserAuthentication /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f&quot;</CommandLine>
                    <Order>3</Order>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                </SynchronousCommand>                
            </FirstLogonCommands>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/users/daniel/downloads/win10_22h2_german_x64/sources/install.wim#Windows 10 Pro" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```